# How to copy 2 million records to csv

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a need to copy 2 million records to a flat file or excel  from the result set, how can i do that?
I tried using where clause with the row number but that is not yielding the results
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Export it with SnowSQL https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-use.html#exporting-data e.g.

```
snowsql -c my_example_connection -d sales_db -s public -q "select * from mytable limit 10" -o output_format=csv -o header=false -o timing=false -o friendly=false  > output_file.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Nat Taylor, "my_example_connection" means "warehouse"."database"."schema" ? and where does this file gets saved to? Where will i run this command in the worksheet?